# Problemas con Accessors and Mutators en Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Siguiendo un ejemplo de L5 en su documentación esto que presento acá debería de imprimir un titulo en mayúscula, solo es un ejemplo ya que lo que quiero realizar es otra cosa pero si con el ejemplo no me funciona es porque algo me anda mal.

acá mi código

```
public function getTituloAttibute()
  {

       return strtoupper($this->title);
  }
```

Eso deberia de devolver un Titulo así TITULO imprimiendo en la vista **{{$article->titulo}}**

Devuelve el valor tal cual esta insertado en la BD

Comment: Tal vez css ? has hecho un dump del valor antes del return? Asumo que el nombre del método es getTituloAttribute() ?

Comment: public function getTituloAttibute()
  {
    dd($this->title);
    return strtoupper($this->title);
  }

Comment: no me imprime nada pero en la BD hay datos para imprimir

Comment: no falta una r en Attribute ?

Comment: Oyeme si es cierto no note eso gracias ahora si me hace el trabajo vale gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay error en el nombre del método (falta una r en Attibute):

```
public function getTituloAttribute()
{
   return strtoupper($this->title);
}
```